# c++ Insertion Sort Count Comparisons

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

I am working on a project that asks us to implement different sorts and add counter variables to measure the runtime with different array sizes. My problem is that my current output is not matching the expected output for my insertion sort.

Any suggestions on what is wrong?

Output:

```
  Array Size:            10         100         1000         10000
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Insertion sort           41         2605       242934     25053573
```

Expected Output:

```
Array Size       10    100    1000      10000
Insertion Sort | 38 | 2600 | 242928 | 25053566
```

Whats inside the contents of the array for array size 10

```
Insertion sort

[ 935, 942, 697, 299, 382, 579, 408, 181, 366, 505 ] //unsorted
[ 181, 299, 366, 382, 408, 505, 579, 697, 935, 942 ] //sorted
```

```
template<class ItemType>
int insertionsort(ItemType theArray[], int n) {
  int counter = 0; //keeps track of number of comparisons

    for (int unsorted = 1; unsorted < n; unsorted++) {
        ItemType nextItem = theArray[unsorted];
        int loc = unsorted;
        counter++;//increment here
        
        while ((loc > 0) && (theArray[loc - 1] > nextItem)) {
          //removed this after comment suggested it
          //if(theArray[loc - 1] > loc){
            counter++; //increment here
          //}
            theArray[loc] = theArray[loc - 1];
            loc--;
        }
        theArray[loc] = nextItem;
    }

    return counter;//returns the number of comaparisons
}


int* makeRandomArray(int n, int seed) {
    srand(seed);
    int * a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % 1000;
    }
    return a;
}

int main(){
    const int seed = 9000;
    /******************************/
    /* Start of Insertion Sort    */
    /******************************/

    std::cout << "Insertion sort";

    n = 10;
    int* a;

    a = makeRandomArray(10, seed);
    std::cout <<std::setw(13)<< insertionsort(a, n);
    delete[] a;

    n = 100;
    a = makeRandomArray(100, seed);
    std::cout <<std::setw(13)<< insertionsort(a, n);
    delete[] a;

    n = 1000;
    a = makeRandomArray(1000, seed);
    std::cout <<std::setw(13)<< insertionsort(a, n);
    delete[] a;

    n = 10000;
    a = makeRandomArray(10000, seed);
    std::cout <<std::setw(13)<< insertionsort(a, n)<<std::endl;
    delete[] a;
}
#endif
```

Comment: What `rand()` returns depends on the environment.

Comment: The result of `n = 10000` case is significantly smaller than expected. This looks like due to too little variety of the elements of the array.

Comment: oh actually i never noticed that

Comment: I was provided with the makeRandomArray, I had to create my own benchmark for this, is the benchmark fine as is or should i change it. Benchmark is what is inside int main()

Comment: Given that the input appears to be randomized, and the actual `counter` value depends on the actual values of the input and their relative order, it is unclear how the "Expected Output" can possibly be a precise, exact value.

Comment: Where does the Expected Output come from? Is it just your thought or are there some external source (the specification of your project, for example)?

Comment: the precise values comes from the array size, since its just counting how many are swapped from the array size and that number should be the same based off that I have to match the expected output.

Comment: The counting depends on not only the array size but also the contents of the array.

Comment: specification of project, I can provide whats inside the array but its just random values.

Comment: I said "This looks like due to too little variety of the elements of the array.", but found that this is actually wrong. The true cause of this significant difference is the weird condition `theArray[loc - 1] > loc`, which is preventing from counting depending on the relation of value and position.

Comment: ah your right, i removed it. but this is output :  41         2605       242934     25053573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counting (`counter++;` is not synchronized with the comparision.

I moved counting to just before comparision and [got the desired result](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8axujLOZUpZM77VO).

```
template<class ItemType>
int insertionsort(ItemType theArray[], int n) {
  int counter = 0; //keeps track of number of comparisons

    for (int unsorted = 1; unsorted < n; unsorted++) {
        ItemType nextItem = theArray[unsorted];
        int loc = unsorted;
        // remove this
        //counter++;//increment here
        
        // add counter++ just before the comparision
        while ((loc > 0) && (counter++, theArray[loc - 1] > nextItem)) {
          if(theArray[loc - 1] > loc){
            // remove this
            //counter++; //increment here
          }
            theArray[loc] = theArray[loc - 1];
            loc--;
        }
        theArray[loc] = nextItem;
    }

    return counter;//returns the number of comaparisons
}
```

Note that what `rand()` returns depends on the environment, so the result may be different on different environment.